# 返り値用の配列に追加するコード

Tags: ruby

```
def hoge(array)
  res = []
  array.each do |data|
    value = data.fuga
    res << value
  end
  res
end
```

こういうことをやってしまうのですが、2行目と5行目と7行目がrubyっぽくないように感じます。

mapなどを使える場面はもっとすっきりかけますが、そうでない時、どうやって書けばrubyらしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

`map` が使えないようなシーンだと、`array.inject([]) { |r, d| r + [d.fuga] }` のように書くことができます。(今回の場合は単純に `array.map(&:fuga)` と書けますが。)

`inject` や `map` では複雑になる場合、泥臭く書く方が良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じで書くのはどうですか？

```
def hoge(array)
  array.map do |data|
    data.fuga
  end
end
```

参考までに、同じようなサンプルコードで、文字列の配列を数値の配列に変換するコードを書いてみました。

```
def hoge(array)
  array.map do |data|
    data.to_i
  end
end

array = %w(1 2 3 4 5)
p hoge(array)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

上の回答とほとんど一緒ですが自分はこんな感じで書いてます↓

```
def hoge(array)
  array.inject([]) do |r, d|
    r += d.fuga
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def hoge(array)
  array.map{ |data| data.fuga }
end
```